# How to sort parent objects in JAVA with respect to their child elements in FIREBASE for android?

Tags: java, android

[This is the Firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv3Es.png)

As shown in the above picture I want to sort the list items with respect to the date they were created. Can someone tell me how to do that! I am using Firebase and Android Studios for the development.

Comment: Show us a sample code you have tried. Are you storing list items in a data structure ?

Comment: Query gofetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("details_user").child(userID).child("Name").orderByValue();I did this to get the

Comment: Query gofetch = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("details_user").child(userID).child("Name").orderByValue();               gofetchlocal.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String userName = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                }
            });  This is the full code

Comment: So I did something like thing to sort the data according to the parent and then called for the child element. But now I want to sort the parent elements according to the value stored in the child element.